# payload sharing - spring integration

Tags: spring-integration

i have a code

```html
 <int-jpa:updating-outbound-gateway
  request-channel="nativeQlChannel" auto-startup="true"
  native-query="update Transactions t set t.transaction_Status = :transactionStatus where t.bank_Reference_Number = :bankReferenceNumber "
  entity-manager="entityManager" persist-mode="PERSIST" reply-channel="nativeQlChannelOne"
  use-payload-as-parameter-source="false">
```

after this execution it calls

```html
 <int-jpa:outbound-channel-adapter
  channel="nativeQlChannel" entity-class="org.ncb.quickpay.grs.persistence.entities.PartnerResponseDetails"
  persist-mode="PERSIST" entity-manager="entityManager" >
  <int-jpa:transactional/>
  </int-jpa:outbound-channel-adapter>

  <int-jpa:outbound-channel-adapter
   channel="nativeQlChannelOne"
   native-query="update Transactions t set t.transaction_Status = :transactionStatus where t.bank_Reference_Number = :bankReferenceNumber "
   entity-manager="entityManager">
   <int-jpa:transactional />
   <int-jpa:parameter name="transactionStatus"
    expression="payload['transactionStatus']" />
   <int-jpa:parameter name="bankReferenceNumber"
    expression="payload['bankReferenceNumber']" />
</int-jpa:outbound-channel-adapter>
```

but i am not able to get any parameter here , as it has 1 as value in payload which is the status of the previous query execution , how can i share the payload so that i can get all parameter which are available to previous query.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A common pattern is to store a reference to the payload in a header; then restore it...

```
<int:header-enricher ...> <!-- before the first gateway -->
    <int:header name="savePayload" expression="payload">
</int:header-enricher>


<int:transformer ... expression="headers.savePayload"> <!-- after the first gateway -->
```

Comment: when you say before firstgateway or after first gateway , where exactly it need to be placed.

Comment: i am using chain but Out-put channel is not executing ? <int:service-activator input-channel="processedItems"
  ref="responseHandler" method="handleResponse" output-channel="dummy">
 </int:service-activator>


 <!-- chain for transaction -->

 <int:chain input-channel="processTransactionChannel"
  output-channel="processedItems">

Comment: Don't put code/config in comments; it's unreadable. Edit the question instead if you need more information.